# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gitlab'

Tags: python, gitlab

For some reason I'm coming across this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gitlab'` after installing python-gitlab.  I installed it via...

- start venv with `source venv/bin/activate`
- `sudo pip install --upgrade python-gitlab` (as per python-gitlab docs)
- Also tried `pip install python-gitlab` (after pip uninstall of previous)
- Followed by a `pip freeze > requirements.txt`
- Then an `import gitlab` at the top of my page

The output after the installation is...

```
Collecting python-gitlab
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: six in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-gitlab) (1.11.0)
Requirement not upgraded as not directly required: requests>=2.4.2 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-gitlab) (2.13.0)
Installing collected packages: python-gitlab
Successfully installed python-gitlab-1.5.1
```

I'm using Python 3.6.4.  What am I doing wrong?